# Simple and inexpensive way to boost high/low digital I/O of microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, push-pull

I'm looking to drive a circuit controlled by a single pin. The pin needs to distinguish between two states (~VCC and GND), needs to be able to act both as a source and a sink, and must be able to source/sink about 100 mA peak current.

This is a bit too much for microcontroller pins, so I've been looking into ways to effectively boost the current rating of the microcontroller pin while preserving the high and low state on the power side. Frequency is a non-issue for virtually any solution (at most 1 change of state a second).

A [push-pull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_output) amplifier seems to do the trick and I'm convinced those exist - similar to Darlington arrays and the like - as ICs but I wasn't able to find any. I only found more involved (and more expensive) chips such as the L293D.

Does anyone know what I'm looking for?

Comment: IXDN609 too expensive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solenoid switching without relays](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/632147/solenoid-switching-without-relays)

Comment: Note, product recommendations are off so instead of asking for specific parts you might want to ask for a class, type, or category of part.

Comment: And just checking, this isn't for driving something like a relay right where you are controlling current flow through a load? Where you don't actually need the "push" functionality? Because just an NPN or NMOS would do in that case.

Comment: The simple NPN/PNP complementary pair shown in your link to a push-pull amplifier is the simplest solution (only two 3-pin parts), although it only drives the output within 0.7V of the power rails. You can get essentially the same circuit in an SOT-363 package https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXGD3009DY.pdf. What you should search for are gate drivers. Some may be rail-to-rail. Perhaps: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/pm8841-1849728.pdf

Comment: You are searching for a gate driver, e.g., UCC27517.

Comment: I don't understand why this was not re-opened, but it has actually been answered well enough without additional answers.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your voltage and bandwidth requirements, a complementary pair of transistors would work, as would a suitable rail-to-rail opamp connected in a voltage follower configuration.

Answer (score 3):

How close do you need to get to the rails on the output? Because a logic-level, complimentary, dual-MOSFET with NMOS on top and PMOS on the bottom will do that but won't get close to the rails, but you don't need to worry about shoot-through.

NMOS on the bottom and PMOS on top will get close to the rails but then you need to deal with shoot-through which means a couple extra resistors.

Or just get some CMOS logic buffer IC (either multiple chips or multiple channels) and wire them all in parallel to achieve your 100mA.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph - IC 'buffers' will often do 24 mA, some will do more.

Comment: +1, I was about to suggest something like 74LVC245 that has 100mA max current (with all outputs in parallel) and is tri-state capable (OP also wants input). That needs 2 pins from the micro though.